# Honey addition to dunkel

Tags: honey

I have a dunkel recipe and I wanted to know if I could simply add honey to the wort making process to add flavor and raise the OG. I am not planning to take anything out as substitution. Are there any problems I could face with this? Will the yeast be fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will raise the OG, but add little to no flavor.  If you want honey flavor to remain, you need to add it to a secondary fermenter.  Even then it will likely be minimal.  If you add honey to the boil, the flavor and aroma will be driven off by boiling and fermentation.  Whether or not the yeast will be fine depends on what yeast you're using, how much of it you pitch, how healthy it is, and what the OG of the beer ends up being.